# How to solve flavor "normal" has no flavor dimension in Android studio 3.0?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

While I was opening an google project called iosched, the gradle building was failed and kept warning me something about flavor. I tried to solve it follow some suggestions online but it turned out to warn me this. What should I do?? My Android studio version is 3.0 btw.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the build.gradle of app module you must define flavorDimensions which is from Android studio 3.0. so do something like :

`android {
    flavorDimensions "example"
}`

and inside ProductFlavors on same module use it as:

`productFlavors {
a {
dimension "example"
}
b{dimension "example"
}`

here a and b are the types of product flavors. 
For more information refer to this link [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error (and several others) after importing a project from version control via Bitbucket hyperlink.

Once imported, close the project and re-import it using `File > New > Import Project`. After that  everything built correctly.
(My productFlavors were already defined properly)

Meta:
`Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 8, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
Gradle 3.4.0`